# Sum of squares and the linear sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics

I'm wondering if I know for a fact

$$\sum_{i=1}^N x_i = k$$

Can I say anything about

$$\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2 = ?$$

Comment: You might be able to get a bound with something like Cauchy-Schwarz, but I highly doubt you can know the value exactly

Comment: impossible to know the value from that anyway : take $x_1=1, x_2 = 1$ and $y_1 = 0.5 , y_2 = 1.5$ then their sum is the same but the squared sum is not.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^N x_i^2 \ge \frac{k^2}{N}$ but there is no upper bound

Comment: If all the terms are possible, it is also true that $\sum_{1 \leq i \leq N} x_i^2 \leq (\sum_{1 \leq i \leq N} x_i)^2 = k^2.$

Comment: @Henry do you mean $\frac{N}{4} \leq \frac{N^2}{4},$ i.e. $N \leq N^2$ which holds for all $N \geq 1$? I don't understand where you're going with this.

Comment: @ActuallyFritz No - but you seem to be assuming $x_i \ge 0$

Comment: @Henry I wanted to write "positive" instead of "possible", my bad. :))))) Of course I was assuming that.

Comment: @ActuallyFritz - OK; so that means for non-negative $x_i$ we can combine our results to say $\dfrac{k^2}{N}\le \sum\limits_{i=1}^N x_i^2 \le k^2$

Comment: @Henry Yup, that is exactly what I was thinking about (Cauchy-Schwarz + the inequality provided by the value of the square of a sum).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^N x_i^2 \ge \frac{k^2}{N}$$ but there is no upper bound in general, though there is if each $x_i\ge 0$.

As an example, let $x_i=z$ and $x_2=-z$ so $\sum\limits_{i=1}^2 x_i =0$ but $\sum\limits_{i=1}^2 x_i^2 = 2z^2$ which is unbounded above.

If you restrict $x_i$ to non-negative values then you can say (like Actually Fritz) that $\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^N x_i\right)^2 \ge \sum\limits_{i=1}^N x_i^2$ by expanding the square of the sum, and so get an upper bound of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^N x_i^2 \le k^2$ for the sum of the squares, and equality iff all but one of the $x_i$ are $0$.

As a proof of the lower bound, you have $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^N \left(x_i-\frac kN\right)^2 \ge 0$$  $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^N x_i^2-2\sum\limits_{i=1}^N x_i \frac kN+ \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \left(\frac kN\right)^2 \ge 0$$ $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^N x_i^2-\frac {k^2}N \ge 0$$
and equality iff each $x_i =\frac{k}{N}$.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid, there is not much you can say.
Consider the simplest case of $x_1$ and $x_2$
$$
x_1 + x_2 = k.
$$
For any
$$
2s^2 > k^2
$$
I can find $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_1 + x_2 &= k,\\ 
x_1^2 + x_2^2 &= s^2.
\end{aligned}
$$
**Proof.** Let's do it constructive.
Suppose
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_1 &= \frac{k-\sqrt{2s^2-k^2}}{2},\\ 
x_2 &= \frac{k+\sqrt{2s^2-k^2}}{2}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Obviously
$$
x_1 + x_2 = \frac{k-\sqrt{2s^2-k^2}+k+\sqrt{2s^2-k^2}}{2}
          = \frac{2k}{2} = k
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_1^2 + x_2^2 &= \frac{k^2-2k\sqrt{2s^2-k^2}+(2s^2-k^2)+k^2+2k\sqrt{2s^2-k^2}+(2s^2-k^2)}{4} =\\
          &= \frac{4s^2}{4} = s^2
\end{aligned}
$$
QED.

Comment: Just noting that if you know the sum and all the $x_i$ except for two then you wouldn't know it anyway :$